# is_enable function in Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to make a script that refreshes a page until BUY Btn is enabled for a certain item (a GPU in my case).
very new to this not sure what im doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

```py
while not buyButton:

    try:
        addButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name("addToCartLabel_YZaVX").is_enabled()
        if addButton.is_enable():
            addButton.click()
        else: browser.refresh()


    except:

        addToCartBtn = addButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name("addToCartLabel_YZaVX")
        print("BtnClick")
        addToCartBtn.click()
        buyButton = True
```

Comment: you forgot to ask a question ;)

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
try:
    addButton=WebDriverWait(browser,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,"addToCartLabel_YZaVX")))
    addButton.click()
except :
    print("Couldn't find the button, doing some other action here)
    #do other stuff here...
    pass
```

Comment: thx but its a item out of stock i want to refresh until the Buy Btn is Enable i dont think in this case the code work.The Product:   https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/nvidia-geforce-rtx-3060-ti-8gb-gddr6-video-card/15166285

Comment: Well, I'm certainly not going to write the entire code for you....check the name of the button against some other page where the button is valid, put it in a loop where you can refresh the page and then run that try/except. the "from..." stuff at the top was there just to help you understand import requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if button is enabled with Selenium's `is_enabled()` [docs here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_enabled) that will return a boolean
So when you do

```py
addButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name("addToCartLabel_YZaVX").is_enabled()
```

you can expect `addButton` to be `True` or `False` if the button you especified before calling `is_enabled()` method is, in fact, enabled (True) or not (False).

So in your next line you are checking if a boolean is enabled, and it won't work :)

Let's just changes some names and do some self-explanatory coding:

```py
while not buyButton:

    try:
        addButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name("addToCartLabel_YZaVX")
        isAddButtonEnabled = addButton.is_enabled 
        if isAddButtonEnabled():
            addButton.click()
        else: browser.refresh()


    except:

        addToCartBtn = addButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name("addToCartLabel_YZaVX")
        print("BtnClick")
        addToCartBtn.click()
        buyButton = True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    try:
        addButton=WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//button[contains(@class,'addToCart')])[1]")))
        addButton.click()
        break
    except:
        browser.refresh()
```

Here's an infinite loop to wait for the element to be clickable for 10 seconds otherwise refresh the page. There's also 4 other classes with that name.

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score -1):

You're already appending ".is_enabled()" at the moment you are declaring the "addButton".

Your if condition is reading like "addButton.is_enabled().is_enabled().

If you remove the first ".is_enabled()" it should work

```
try:
addButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name("addToCartLabel_YZaVX")
if addButton.is_enabled():
    addButton.click()
else: browser.refresh()
```

Comment: hmm there something else wrong with my code then. its going to the except part even do the BTN is disable. thx btw

Comment: the class name is probably not defined correctly...

Comment: https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/nvidia-geforce-rtx-3060-ti-8gb-gddr6-video-card/15166285      trying to click on the add to cart BTN